# LINQ to Entities not supported crystal reports

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, crystal-reports

I'm trying to output a simple calculation to a crystal reports viewer in my WPF application. I'm currently getting "The specified type member 'StockSaleValue' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

**Update**

Fixed with

```
 using (CrystalReportsTestEntities db = new CrystalReportsTestEntities())
        {
            var stocks = db.Stocks.ToList().Where(item => item.StockSaleValue > 5);
            report.SetDataSource(stocks);
        }
```

Comment: Instead of `.ToList()` you should use `.AsEnumerable()` since `.ToList()` iterates through the complete dataset and converts in into a list, where `.AsEnumerable()` just loops lazily through the collection.

Comment: When you find a solution, you should post it as a solution. Or, since @Sheridan clearly provided the basis for your answer, you should mark that answer as correct and up-vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?:

```
using (CrystalReportsTestEntities db = new CrystalReportsTestEntities())
{
    List<Stock> stocks = db.Stocks.Where(item => item.StockSalePrice > 5).ToList();
    report.SetDataSource(stocks);
}
```

Comment: Yes I've tried that and its still giving me the same error.

Comment: The issue occurs within the `Where` clause itself. `StockSalePrice` is a calculated client-side property, and cannot be translated to the where clause of the SQL query. The `ToList()` would have to occur before the `Where` clause if the `Stock` class remains as-is.